# How did Alice get boots in the hospital?

Tags: movie, through-the-looking-glass

When Alice escapes the hospital she's barefoot.  Then when she gets to the roof she suddenly has boots on.  How did she get boots on when the whole time we saw her escaping the hospital she was escaping them barefoot, running up to the roof, and didn't stop?

So how did she suddenly get boots on?

Answer (score 4):

At the top of the stairs was a coat-rack and, **presumably just hidden from view, a shoe-rack with at least one pair of boots.**

Since she had time to put on the coat before opening the door, there's obviously a *very slight time-jump* where she would have had ample opportunity to put her feet into some (laceless) mens boots before exiting onto the rooftop.

Comment: The above presumption seems out of place in an attempt to answer a “literary critical” question like this.  I could as well presume that behind the door was a little wizard who quickly befriended Alice, and who sold her the mysterious boots, for the gold that Alice presumably had hidden in the purple corset we never see her wear.

Comment: @ferjsoto42yahoocom - Why yes, it's far more likely that Alice briefly befriended a wizard than that a shoe-rack would be found underneath a coat-rack.

Comment: If one is to go along this route, then skip the shoe-rack altogether. After all, you just need the boots.  If one is going  to introduce unnecessary stuff, then why would one then object to boot-selling wizards?

Answer (score -2):

She may have come across the boots that disappeared from The Hunting of the Snark.  Some people think that the Baker identified the Boo(ts) as the former vanishes, but I tend to think that the mysterious boots may have been found by Alice in this episode.